# JTestcase for data in xml files with JUnit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, testcase

I looked upon some years old code which uses JTestcase for separating data from Test case(JTestCase basically helps to manage data in xml files). 
So JTestCase is integrated with JUnit test cases code.

Jar available for JTestcase is 2006 version so i guess there is no new release for same. This makes me think that probably JTestCase is old thing to use otherwise they would have provided new version.

Please tell me if there is some new technology in place of JTestCase and if not what are negatives of Jtestcase(like one can be performance considering fact that it allows use of xml files which is itself in trade off with better organization of complex data).

I couldn't find Maven artifact for JTestcase. Please let me know if it is available on any site.

Which site is good dependable source to find maven artifact. Currently i see https://repository.sonatype.org/index.html#welcome for same purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems like a lot of effort to go to just to write a unit test.
I think the negative of using JTestCase is doubling the amount of code you have to write.
I wouldn't use this framework unless you could see some significant benefit to putting your test data into XML. I think doing this for tests would make it harder to maintain in most cases!